# Tools for architecture & design of medium-big R projects

Tags: r, architecture

As I'm starting to build relatively big projects in R (>30 functions), I feel the need for more systematic architecture & design thinking. I'm looking for tools that would make it easier for me to have a high-level overview of my code, as well as explaining to others what my code does.

To give you a more concrete idea of what I do: I typically work on the automation of data mining experiments that have been successful. Such a project usually involves:

1. importing data
2. data cleaning & transformation
3. report with descriptive statistics
4. processing of a battery of algorithms & models
5. report that summarizes the results.

What kind of software tools and what kind of methodology should I use ?

Comment: @Andrie I am writing packages for what I do, and it helps indeed, once the right design has been identified. However the way to get there is painful: I often have to change low-level design elements multiple times until I have something with the right level of flexibility and robustness...

Comment: Ah, that's the joy of software development, isn't it?

Comment: I think this question is at risk to getting closed.  It probably really belongs on programmers (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange). If you feel it belongs here, then I suggest you edit the question to be much more specific. What do you use at the moment? Where do you get stuck?